# Laravel eloquent postgresql support

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-9

Basic laravel `hasMany` relation doesn't work out of the box for `postgres`?

I'm trying this:

```php
$categories = Category::with('products')->get();
```

where `products` relation is:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

SQL query which it tries to make looks like:

```sql
select
  *
from
  "products"
where
  "products"."category_id" IN (...)
```

which is not a valid syntax for `postgres`

Am I missing something? Driver is set to `pgsql`

The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer LINE 1: ... 
* from "products" where "products"."category_id" in (13, 14... 
^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: That is valid syntax: `select * from animals where animal in ('dog', 'cat')   45 | poor | dog`. To your question add the complete error message you get.

Comment: What is the schema for `products`? Is `category_id` a varchar or integer?

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: `... operator does not exist: character varying = integer`. Either make the ids in the `IN()` `varchar` or cast `category_id` to `integer`.

Comment: did you try this way inside products function ?   return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id')->selectRaw('*, category_id::integer');

Comment: Make `products.category_id` the same column type as `categories.id` in your migrations. According to the error message, it seems one of these is a varchar. PostgreSQL complains about implicit casts way more than MySQL

Comment: Is the relationship not backed by a foreign key constraint?  I guess it must not be, else the type mismatch issue should have turned up there, first.  So why not?